# Drupal 7 Custom module - Send form contents through Ajax, then get JSON response

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have the following code in my custom module expertsqa.module

```
function expertsqa_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['expertsqa/answerquestion'] = array( 
  'title' => 'Answer question', //page title
  'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
  'page arguments' => array('expertsqa_answer_form'), //put the name of the form here
  'access callback' => TRUE
);

  return $items;
}

function expertsqa_answer_form($form, &$form_state) {

drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'expertsqa') . '/js/jquery.form.js');

$suffix = '
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(\'#expertsqa-answer-form\').ajaxForm({
        target: "#output"
    });
 });
</script>
';

$form['price'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea', 
    '#title' => 'Type Answer',
    '#rows' => 5,
    '#columns' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE, 
'#suffix' => $suffix,
);

$form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
);

return $form;
}

function expertsqa_answer_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_json_output(array('foo', 'baa'));
    drupal_exit();
}
```

I want to submit the form's content through ajaxform JQuery plugin, which is working fine, and then want it to be processed by the function expertsqa_answer_form_submit which should return a JSON response. Please someone tell me the correct way to do this as it is returning full html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include any JavaScript to accomplish this. This is part of the power of Drupal.

It's a lot to explain here, and it has already been done before. I suggest you read this:

https://drupal.org/node/752056

If you read that documentation, I am certain you will be able to accomplish what you are setting out to do here.

Long story short, is within a form you have elements that trigger an ajax call and then elements that are reloaded when it is called. During this process the entire form_state can be re-processed. Once you get the hang of it you will see its extremely powerful.

If you update your code to proper Drupal convention and still can't get it working reply here and I will update my answer to help you.

Good luck!